# Extend a stream to allow seamless multistreams from http in C#

Tags: c#, stream

Currently I am using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to check the StatusCode and download a file.

The file I am downloading, is **either a .zip-file** (which I try first) or **a part of a .zip file** (.z01, .z02, etc.). Since the part-files are always 20 megabyte in size (in my case), I can check whether I downloaded exactly 20 megabytes and if so, attempt to continue with the next part. If not, I will assume, that I was downloading the last part.

In order to achieve that in Java, I would extend the InputStream and override its read-method and return the next stream inside of it, reading from the current stream or closing it and using HttpURLConnection to retrieve the next stream - or assuming it was the last stream if there is no next stream.

I *tried extending **Stream** in c#*, but since the Stream-class is abstract, I have to implement quite a few methods, that I do not really need / want to implement. ***BufferedStream*** is sealed. So my only other option is to extend ***MemoryStream*** if I do not want to implement all the methods of a Stream-class.

**What would be a good approach to do this in c#?**

The reason I need a stream, is, that I am processing the stream (unzipping/decoding) it - which works flawlessly for the single .zip-files already. Since I can also specify the offset, I would be able to download from a offset.
For multi-part streams I would translate the given offset into the correct part file name by dividing it by 20 megabytes.

**Edit:** I rejected adding the zip and decode as tags, because it does not really matter which file-type I am downloading (by the way: it is not a true zip, but a LZMA-encoded file, which I decode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is probably not the best one nor did I test the **Position**-attribute, but it does the job.

I derived a class from [Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and and implemented a wrapper around it, that deals with setting the **currentStream**-object.

The files on the server are usually saved in either .zip or .z01, .z02, .z03 etc. The MultiPartStream(string) constructor lets the MultiPartStream "guess" the correct URL. GetPart() usually suppresses the errors while checking the response. The MultiPartStream(string, string) constructor simply allows to download a file while also returning Transferspeed.

I will probably be changing this class as I go, but this already does what I need and since I do not like having an open question, I decided to provide a response, which worked for me. I might update it later if I end up changing it a lot.

Thinking about this though, I probably could have sub-classed [NetworkStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. Perhaps I will change this, but so far this MultiPartStream works well and it actually uses all the bandwidth, that I have. Plus it has TotalStreamSize and Transferspeed.

*MultiPartStream.cs*:

```
using MyProject.Logic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject.Model
{
    public class MultiPartStream : Stream
    {
        private HttpWebResponse response;
        private Stream currentStream;
        private List<KeyValuePair<string, long>> parts = new List<KeyValuePair<string,long>>();

        private Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        private long totalStreamSize;
        private long bytesRead;
        private string file;
        private int currentPart = 0;

        public MultiPartStream(string file)
        {
            this.file = file;
            GetParts();
            NextStream();
        }

        public MultiPartStream(string file, string url)
        {
            this.file = file;
            GetPart(url, false);
            NextStream();
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            if (!timer.IsRunning)
                timer.Start();

            int bytesRead = currentStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            if (bytesRead <= 0 && currentPart < parts.Count - 1)
            {
                // if we cannot read from the Stream anymore, we open the next Stream if one is available
                currentPart++;
                NextStream();
                bytesRead = Read(buffer, offset, count);
            }
            this.bytesRead += bytesRead;

            return (int)bytesRead;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void GetParts()
        {
            if (!this.GetPart(DownloadHelper.Instance.GetSingleFileUrl(file)))
            {
                int filePart = 1;
                while (this.GetPart(DownloadHelper.Instance.GetMultiFileUrl(file, filePart)))
                {
                    filePart++;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool GetPart(string url, bool suppressApplicationException = true)
        {
            bool thisPartAdded = false;

            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (request.HaveResponse && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    parts.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, long>(url, response.ContentLength));
                    totalStreamSize += response.ContentLength;
                    thisPartAdded = true;
                }
                response.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                if (!suppressApplicationException)
                    throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Error: cannot access file '{0}' ({1}: {2})", url, e.Status, e.Message));
            }

            return thisPartAdded;
        }

        private void NextStream()
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
                response = null;
            }

            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(parts[currentPart].Key);

            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (request.HaveResponse && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    currentStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("Error: could not open file '{0}' for streaming ({1}: {2})", parts[currentPart].Key, e.Status, e.Message));
            }
        }

        public long TotalStreamSize
        {
            get { return totalStreamSize; }
        }

        public string TransferSpeed
        {
            get
            {
                float transferSpeed = (float)(bytesRead / 1024f) / (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000f);
                if (transferSpeed > 1024f)
                {
                    return "@ " + Math.Round(transferSpeed / 1024f, 2) + " mb / s";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "@ " + Math.Round(transferSpeed, 2) + " kb / s";
                }
            }
        }

        #region Remaining Stream-methods
        public override long Position
        {
            get
            {
                long valueToCompare = 0;
                for (int index = 0; index < currentPart; index++)
                {
                    valueToCompare += parts[index].Value;
                }
                return valueToCompare + currentStream.Position;
            }
            set
            {
                long valueToCompare = 0;
                for (int index = 0; index < parts.Count; index++)
                {
                    valueToCompare += parts[index].Value;
                    if (value <= valueToCompare)
                    {
                        currentPart = index;
                        NextStream();
                        currentStream.Position = value - (valueToCompare - parts[index].Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override bool CanSeek
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            if (currentPart > 0)
            {
                currentPart = 0;
                NextStream();
            }
            else if (currentPart == 0)
            {
                currentStream.Flush();
            }
        }

        public override long Length
        {
            get { return totalStreamSize; }
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Other relevant methods:

```
public string GetSingleFileUrl(string file)
{
    return String.Format("{0}/Zip/{1}.zip", this.GetBaseUrl(), file.Replace(@"\", "/"));
}

public string GetMultiFileUrl(string file, int part)
{
    return String.Format("{0}/Zip/{1}.z{2:D2}", this.GetBaseUrl(), file.Replace(@"\", "/"), part);
}
```

This class is not perfect as it is strictly written for a certain file source, but it does its job. If I end up improving it to an extent where I am really happy with it, I will make sure to update my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this in the methods you don't need to actually implement...

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Comment: I thought about that, but while I might not be using them, they might be used somehow somewhere - which is why I would avoid setting CanRead / CanWrite etc. to "throw new NotImplementedException();".